# ¿Cómo registrar con Transacciones en Symfony?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, symfony4

> **Problema:** Trato de realizar un registro de Salida y DetalleSalida
> usando transacciones en Symfony 5.

- **En Laravel**: Logre hacer esto en Laravel 5.4, pero no se como pasarlo a Symfony 5.

  ```
   DB::beginTransaction();
   $salida=new Salida;

   $salida->n_salida=$request->get('n_salida');
   $mytime=Carbon::now('America/La_Paz');
   $salida->fecha_salida=$mytime->toDateTimeString(); 
   $salida->paciente_id=$request->get('paciente_id');
   $salida->destino=$request->get('destino');
   $salida->descripcion_salida=$request->get('descripcion_salida');
   $salida->total_salida=$request->get('total_salida');
   $salida->estado="Activo";
   $salida->save();

   $codigo_med=$request->get('codigo_med');//Para el while
   $cantidad_salida=$request->get('cantidad_salida');
   $precio_venta=$request->get('precio_venta');

   $cont=0;

   while($cont < count($codigo_med))
   {
       $detalle= new DetalleSalida();
       $detalle->salida_id=$salida->salida_id;
       $detalle->codigo_med=$codigo_med[$cont];
       $detalle->precio_venta=$precio_venta[$cont];
       $detalle->cantidad_salida=$cantidad_salida[$cont];
       $detalle->save();
       $cont=$cont+1;
   }
   DB::commit();
  ```
- **Mis entidades se relacionan así:**

**- Salida:**

```
/**  
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\DetalleSalida", mappedBy="salida", cascade={"persist","remove"})  
*/ 

private $detallesalida;

public function setDetalleSalida(?array $detallesalida): self
{
    $this->detallesalida = $detallesalida;
    return $this;
}
```

**- DetalleSalida:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Salida", inversedBy="detallesalida")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="salida_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $salida;

public function getSalida(): ?Salida
{
    return $this->salida;
}

public function setSalida(?Salida $salida): self
{
    $this->salida = $salida;

    return $this;
}
```

- **Mi formulario de salida (SalidaType)**: Llamando el formulario de detalle dentro del mismo.

  ```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('tipo_comprobante')
            ->add('serie_comprobante')
            ->add('num_comprobante')
            ->add('fecha_hora',DateType::class)
            ->add('estado')
            ->add('tipo_pago')
            ->add('total_compra')
            ->add('deuda')
            ->add(
                $builder->create('detallesalida', DetalleSalidaType::class, ['by_reference' => false])
            ) 
            ->add('Guardar',SubmitType::class) 
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Salida::class,
        ]);
    }
  ```
- **Mi error es el siguiente:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- **De momento lo llevo así mi Controller:**

Trato de replicar lo que hice en laravel, en Symfony, pero llamando el form de detalle, dentro de salida, pero no se como referenciar los inputs de la misma.

```
class SalidaController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/salida', name: 'salida')]
    public function index(Request $request): Response
    {
        $post=new Salida();
        $form = $this->createForm(SalidaType::class,$post);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            //$em->$this->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            try {
                    $salida = new Salida();
                    $salida->setTipoComprobante($form['tipo_comprobante']->getData());
                    $salida->setSerieComprobante($form['serie_comprobante']->getData());
                    $salida->setNumComprobante($form['num_comprobante']->getData());
                    $salida->setFechaHora($form['fecha_hora']->getData());
                    $salida->setEstado($form['estado']->getData());
                    $salida->setTipoPago($form['tipo_pago']->getData());
                    $salida->setTotalCompra($form['total_compra']->getData());
                    $salida->setDeuda($form['deuda']->getData());
                    $salida->setDetalleSalida($form['detallesalida']->getData());
                    $em->persist($salida);
                    $em->flush();
                } 
            catch (Exception $e) 
                {
                    $em->getConnection()->rollBack();
                    throw $e;
                }
                 
            return $this->redirectToRoute('salida');
        }

       return $this->render('salida/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'SalidaController',
        'form' => $form->createView(),
       ]);

    }
}
```

> GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO.

Comment: Si no me equivoco el `getConnection()->beginTransaction();` deberías invocarlo doble el entityManager (`$em`) igual que en el rollback hay un `this->` que te sobra ahi

Comment: El error que te aparece se debe a que estas intentando añadir una entity DetalleSalida en el set, pero solo le permites array o null. `public function setDetalleSalida(?array $detallesalida): self` deberia ser ``public function setDetalleSalida(?DetalleSalida $detallesalida): self
``

Comment: @Xerif  funciona con el "getDoctrine()->getManager();" ya que no me reconoce la funcion "getConnection()".

Comment: Doctrine por defecto ya utiliza transactions de manera implícita, [enlace](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#approach-1-implicitly). Estás utilizando la otra forma por alguna razón en particular?